# Windows Service - Multiple Setup projects required?

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a windows service having different config files for dev, test and live environments.
For each of these, I have created separate setup projects like 'ServiceDevSetup', 'ServiceTestSetup' and 'ServiceLiveSetup' (with their pre/post build events setup).

I was wondering if it is really required to have these separate projects or can I do with just one setup project?

Is there any way I can have just one setup project and then at the build time, I get prompt for which config file to use?

Please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build it all into a single .msi and then arrange that the bootstrapper passes a parameter to the installer to specify which of the configs you desire.  That would give a nice decoupling and make maintenance easier.